# In Blazor, can I create a file input dynamically without attaching it to the DOM? (Pick file button)

Tags: .net, input, blazor, blazor-webassembly, filepicker

What I want to achieve is the equivalent of this Javascript: a button that can pick a file and process that file.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "file";
  input.onchange = () => alert("You picked: " + input.files[0]?.name);
  input.click();
});
```

```html
<button>Pick File</button>
```

I tried creating an `InputFile` but the reference is not there (Id and Context are `null`s):

```html
    <div class="text-center mt-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@this.AddFiles">
            @("AddFiles".Loc())
        </button>
    </div>
```

```cs
    async Task AddFiles()
    {
        var input = new InputFile();
        await this.Js.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerClick", input.Element);
        // triggerClick is a Javascript method that click the element
    }
```

---

My current workaround attach an invisible `input` into the DOM and even then it's not exactly simple:

```html
    @inject IJSRuntime Js;

    <div class="text-center mt-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.AddFiles">
            @("AddFiles".Loc())
        </button>
    </div>

    @if (this.fileRequested)
    {
        <InputFile @ref="this.txtFile" OnChange="this.OnFileChanged" class="d-none" />
    }
```

```cs
    bool fileRequested = false;
    InputFile? txtFile;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (this.fileRequested && this.txtFile is not null)
        {
            await this.Js.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerClick", this.txtFile.Element);
        }
    }

    async Task AddFiles()
    {
        this.fileRequested = true;
    }

    async Task OnFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.fileRequested = false;

        await this.Js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "You picked: " + e.File?.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
 <InputFile id="filePickerId" OnChange="this.OnFileChanged" class="d-none"></InputFile>


<label for="filePickerId">
    <button type="button" style="pointer-events: none;">Pick a file</button>
</label>



async Task OnFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await this.Js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "You picked: " + e.File?.Name);
    }
```

Comment: This one results in an `input` in the DOM. And you don't even dynamically create it.